# I needs to execute one sql query against two DBs in at a time and export the data to csv files

Tags: linux, shell, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I am calling sql query inside the shell script and executing the two queries in background like below.
Also am using the DB config file to get the db user and password. like below.

```
....
#!bin/bash
    sqlplus -S ${user1}@${DBCONNECTIONNAME_1}/${Pwd} Datesquery.sql & >> ${Targetdirectory}/csvfile1.csv
                     sqlplus -S ${user1}@${DBCONNECTIONNAME_2}/${Pwd} Datesquery.sql $ >> ${Targetdirectory}/csvfile2.csv
                     sed 1d csvfile2.csv > file2noheader.csv
                     cat csvfile1.csv file2noheader.csv > ${Targetdirectory}/Expod.csv
```

....
But it giving me the error as showing manual to connecting the db, but I can able to connect to sqlplus utility directly, please let me know how to connect to db and execute script background and export to csv files in side the shellscripting.

Comment: What error exactly is generated?  show output please

Comment: What are the `&` and `$` characters before the `>>` redirections?

Comment: Add a line `set -x` after `#!bin/bash` or run your script with `bash -x yourscript` and check if the executed commands are what you expect.

Comment: Both are &, for running query in the background and getting error message as /test/csvfile1.csv no such file or directory and immediate of  showing sqlplus connection manual.Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Use SQL*Plus to execute SQL, PL/SQL and SQL*Plus statements.

Usage 1: sqlplus -H | -V

    -H             Displays the SQL*Plus version and the
                   usage help.

Comment: @jon heller, thanks for reply. I have config file and used the source command get the prop DB connection strings and now it is connecting to db but gives./script2.sh: line 105: /temp/test_sql/sqlextracted/data/csvfile1.csv: No such file or directory
./script2.sh: line 106: /temp/test_sql/sqlextracted/data/csvfile2.csv: No such file or directory, I used above with including spool command inside the sql query and it works but when I direct the output within the shell script, it throws above error message.